# pagination using velocity

Tags: java, spring-mvc, velocity

Is their is macros / tools available for pagination in velocity (spring used as framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [org.apache.velocity.tools.view.PagerTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/view/PagerTool.html)
 which allows you to page through a list of items.

Comment: can you give one example please ?

Comment: The showcase app that comes with VelocityTools has an example.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative approach you can use some JQuery plugin that handles all client-side processing and take data from the server-side code. In that case you can generate a plain table with velocity, and plugin will add pagination dinamically on the server-side.
You migh try http://www.datatables.net/ because it handles pagination, filtering, ordering and has much more features. Here is explained how you can integrate DataTables with java servlet application http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/JQuery-DataTables-Java.aspx. In this example is used JSP and servlet but you can easily change this to velocity because server side code is simple.